# MySQL insists that field does not exist, then tells me that it does exist

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

CentOS 4 or 5, with MySQL 5.0.77:

```
mysql> UPDATE
   ->  `userTable`
   -> INNER JOIN `anotherTable`
   ->   ON `userTable.userid`=`anotherTable.userid`
   -> SET `userTable.someField`="Jimmy Page"
   -> WHERE `userTable.someField`="Jim Morrison"
   ->   AND `anotherTable.date` < NOW();
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'userTable.someField' in 'field list'
mysql>
mysql> SELECT count(someField) FROM userTable;
+---------------+
| count(someField) |
+---------------+
|          5076 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I did enter the someField and userTable into the SELECT statement by mouse-copy/pasting in the terminal, so I know that it is not a typo issue. What could be the issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: it seems caused by back tick. try remove it them try again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tick marks are used for quoting columns and table names.  With the dot in the quotes, it is not seeing that as a divider between the parts.  Add a couple extra tick marks to correct it.

```
 UPDATE
  `userTable`
 INNER JOIN `anotherTable`
   ON `userTable`.`userid`=`anotherTable`.`userid`
 SET `userTable`.`someField`="Jimmy Page"
 WHERE `userTable`.`someField`="Jim Morrison"
   AND `anotherTable`.`date` < NOW();
```

Comment: or dun use any back tick at all

Comment: Considering that one of their fields is 'date' they will need to use some back ticks.  Otherwise, your right.  It does have too many.

Comment: fyi date is not  reserved word in mysql.it is a  design problem when using the reserved keywords as column or table name

Comment: Your right, in the example given, no back ticks are actually needed.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually the first project that I've ever used the backticks in, precisely because there are reserved words used for column names. It is a habit that I think I should get into.